# predict_classes returning a conflicting shape for a LSTM classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, lstm

I have quite a bit of trouble understanding the expected shape of the input/output for an LSTM problem.

Specifically for this example I have **386** of length **100** each containing **14** features. For each such sequence, I need only predict whether it is in the **0** or **1** class. The respective shapes and model are

```
X_test.shape,y_test.shape
((358, 100, 14), (358, 1))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,14)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy' , metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now if (after fitting) I want to predict the output of the model, the shape of the prediction is inconsistent with y_test!

```
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
y_pred.shape
(358, 100, 1)
```

Here I'd expect the shape to match `y_test`, and be (358,1) instead of the output given by `predict_classes()`

I am clearly misunderstanding something here. What am I missing here? Is there a different way to tackle this problem altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the 3rd dim of the LSTM `return_sequences=True`, where the input to the last sigmoid layer will be 3D. Thus, the sigmoid layer will be applied on the last dim.

Just do the following:

```
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=False,input_shape=(None,14)))
```